# How to translate and rotate in bitmap in android?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I am trying to translate and rotate a bitmap in android `ImageView`. But I can't get the result. Any pointers will be helpful.

```
    int width = mb.getWidth();
    int height = mb.getHeight();

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preTranslate(width/2, height/2)
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mb, 0, 0,
                      width, height, matrix, true);
    imageview.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```